# Why did this UPDATE change all rows instead of just one row?

Tags: sql

I have made some SQL code to (what I thought) would update 1 field for only some records. The code I made was:

```
UPDATE Name
SET name.STATUS = 'a'
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT Name.ID,
            Name.MEMBER_TYPE,
            Name.CATEGORY,
            Name.STATUS,
            Name.COMPANY_SORT,
            Name.FULL_NAME,
            Name.TITLE,
            Name.FUNCTIONAL_TITLE,
            Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE,
            Activity.PRODUCT_CODE,
            Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE
     FROM Name
     INNER JOIN Activity ON Name.ID = Activity.ID
     WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'ELECTIONS'
       AND PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '%new%'
       AND TRANSACTION_DATE LIKE '%2014%'
       AND name.MEMBER_TYPE IN ('mcm',
                                'MCNM'))
```

but it updated all the records in the name name to the status of `a`, not just the one in the where exist statement ... what have I screwed up?

Comment: Run the SELECT statement on its own; that will show you which rows are affected.  It will be more than you expected.  Note that the `Name` in the SELECT is separate from the `Name` in the UPDATE; that is, the sub-query is not a correlated sub-query with the row in the UPDATE.

Comment: I think that the reason is because as soon as you have one record returned by your SELECT, the EXISTS condition is verified which leads to a full update as there is no other condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE Name
SET name.STATUS = 'a'
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM Activity
     WHERE Name.ID = Activity.ID
       AND ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'ELECTIONS'
       AND PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '%new%'
       AND TRANSACTION_DATE LIKE '%2014%'
       AND name.MEMBER_TYPE IN ('mcm', 'MCNM')
    )
```

Some explanation: when you do `FROM Name` in the inner query you mask outer table `Name` and just query whole thing. So inner query is the same for every entry. You need to reuse `Name` from outer query so that inner query relates to outer. Sorry, my code might need some polishing I don't even know what DB you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the outer query "Name" table to the subquery.  Note the addition in the where criteria.  I haven't run this, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
    UPDATE Name
SET name.STATUS = 'a'
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT innerName.ID,
            innerName.MEMBER_TYPE,
            innerName.CATEGORY,
            innerName.STATUS,
            innerName.COMPANY_SORT,
            innerName.FULL_NAME,
            innerName.TITLE,
            innerName.FUNCTIONAL_TITLE,
            Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE,
            Activity.PRODUCT_CODE,
            Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE
     FROM Name innerName
     INNER JOIN Activity ON innerName.ID = Activity.ID
     WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'ELECTIONS'
AND innerName.ID = Name.ID
       AND PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '%new%'
       AND TRANSACTION_DATE LIKE '%2014%'
       AND innerName.MEMBER_TYPE IN ('mcm',
                                'MCNM'))
```

Comment: You don't need all that long list of fields because it is `EXISTS`.

Comment: True, but it will still work.  I just copy/pasted the OP's code, with the addition of the piece the criteria that will make it work as he expects.

Answer (score 0):

There's no link between the data selection of the UPDATE statement, versus what you define in the SUB-SELECT (that starts after the EXISTS clause). Basically, it says to update all, if the below select has any record at all.

The EXISTS clause is not intelligent enough to know what record you are talking about. You have to tell him.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your reference to `Name` in the update line and your reference to `Name` under the sub-query are treated as two separate instances, so there is no relation between the update statement and the sub-query.

To get around it, you can actually alias your tables within the sub-query itself, and then explicitly refer to the alias in the update:

```
UPDATE nm
SET nm.STATUS = 'a'
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM Name nm
     INNER JOIN Activity act ON nm.ID = act.ID
     WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'ELECTIONS'
       AND PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '%new%'
       AND TRANSACTION_DATE LIKE '%2014%'
       AND nm.MEMBER_TYPE IN ('mcm',
                              'MCNM'))
```