# I want to edit a specific row in database

Tags: node.js, database, jsx

`[userList.jsx]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/19EbJ.png),
`[EditUser.jsx]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GyU8.png),
`[backend.js]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsx38.png)

I want to update the data in my database using a form called user List. I want to Update data of that row that's Edit button I click, my current problem is when I click Edit and fill the details to update, it gets update all rows of database

Comment: How does the query know what id to use to modify any single row, if not sent in the request?

Comment: see: [Why did this UPDATE change all rows instead of just one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110694/why-did-this-update-change-all-rows-instead-of-just-one-row)

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and Welcome to stackoverflow.com